# Ambiguous template class constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, ambiguous

I'm implementing a N-dimensional array library. Consider this code:

```
template<int Rank, class Type>
class Array {
{
public:
    // constructor for vectors, valid when Rank==1
    Array(int dim0, Type val = Type());

    // constructor for matrices, valid when Rank==2
    Array(int dim0, int dim1, Type val = Type());
    ...
}
```

The problem is that if `Type == int`, the compiler will complain about ambiguous constructor call (for example, `Array<1,int>(1,1)`). Is there a trick like `enable_if` that makes the compiler ignore constructors that don't match `Rank`? (without C++11 please)

Thank you

Comment: @Daniel Ops, it should be `int Rank`, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use template specialization for this:

```
template<int size, class Type>
class Array {
// General stuff for size > 2, if you have any
};


template <class Type>
class Array<1, Type>
{
// Code for one-dimensional array
};


template <class Type>
class Array<2, Type>
{
// Code for two-dimensional array
};
```

or even specify it for int exactly:

```
template <>
class Array<2, int>
{
// Code for two-dimensional integer array
};
```

It is also perfectly valid for them to have totally different set of public interfaces.

But I would probably pass an array or `std::vector` of given size for dimensions or remove the third argument, just add a method, say, `populate(Type t)` to do the trick (and it may be also useful not only for constructing).